# leetcode twoSum: order of elements in the result list

Tags: python

I just started to solve the problems in leetcode with python. When I solve the problem of two sum: [Two Sum of LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/). I found the order of the result element in my list are reversed comparing to the correct answer. My code is below:

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        #Original Solution
        num0 = -1
        num1 = -1
        num_map = dict(zip(nums, range(len(nums))))
        for key in nums:
            rem = target - key
            if rem not in num_map:
                continue
            else:
                num0 = num_map[key]
                num1 = num_map[rem]
        return [num0, num1]



sol = Solution()
test = sol.twoSum([3,2,4], 6)
```

The test case is: [3, 2, 4] and the target is 6. The correct answer should be [1, 2], while my answer is [2, 1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to print the two indices in the array whose value sum is target value. In the given case of [3,2,4], as you are looping on all three values and comparing in all values of the dict always, you can break the loop in first occurrence of solution.

```
for key in nums:
    rem = target - key
    if rem not in num_map or **rem==key**:
        continue
    else:
        num0 = num_map[key]
        num1 = num_map[rem]
        **break**
return [num0, num1]
```

Also there is a case where both key and remaining values (3,3) can be same as you are looping on all values of dictionary. So you need to make sure that you handle this case.

Note: I tried to make least changes (above) in your code and not rewrite it.

EDIT: Simplified version of your code

```
for key in nums:
    rem = target - key
    if rem in num_map and rem!=key:
        return [num_map[key], num_map[rem]]
```

Comment: @JoshuaW1990 if you like the answer then can you upvote or accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation for upvoting options now : (

Comment: @JoshuaW1990 please refer to the below link. You can accept answer with out enough reputations. Thanks
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work